# Entity Framework Core - DBContext collisions with multiple AJAX calls

Tags: c#, ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core project that I am migrating from EF6 to .NET 5 with Entity Framework Core. Whilst the migration has mostly gone smoothly, I'm having trouble with a particular page which works fine in the old WebForms version, but has issues in .NET Core.

My project is a fairly standard .NET 5 web application, which makes use of several "services" for fetching real-time data from a database using AJAX. These services are dependency-injected into the controllers using standard .NET Core DI. For the purposes of this question, I'm trying to fetch a user by username. I send the AJAX request to "UserController" which calls the "UserService" which has a "UserRepository" on it, which is where the actual DBContext lives. The problem I'm having is that on one particular page, it fetches many users from the database in quick succession using four separate AJAX calls which all ultimately call the same Repository function, and its resulting in a "A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed" error. I'm not clear why this is happening, as while I'm aware that DBContext is not thread-safe, I would have expected .NET Core DI to be clever enough to create a new DBContext to handle each thread separately, but clearly this isn't the case.

**Things that I have tried:**

**1. Setting the DBContext, Repository and Service lifetimes to
"Transient".**

This seems to make no difference whatsoever. Most of my services, repositories e.t.c are registered as "AddScoped" by default. I had read somewhere that if a class is registered as scoped, then any class under it will have the same scope, so there is no point making them transient. To that end, after making the DBContext transient I tried also making the repository transient, then finally the service, but nothing seemed to make a difference. This is odd, because my understanding was that "transient" services should be creating new instances every time they're called, so I'm not sure how its possible for the same DBContext to be being used in this instance. I may have simply done something wrong here.

**2. Setting everything to "async Task" with awaits**

Googling this problem most commonly I find people with the same issue who have simply missed an "await" somewhere, resulting in a thread collision. As far as I can tell, everything in the stack leading up to the code that throws the error is async, returning a Task with an await.

**3. Creating a new DBContext for every request manually with a "using" block**

This simply leads to a different issue with dependency injection; "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: "IServiceProvider". I'm not super clear what's going on here but I believe that this is because the constructor for my DBContext takes in a DbContextOptions with the connection strings e.t.c in it, which is passed in by dependency injection. It seems as though something is happening in the course of the garbage collection process that is "cleaning up" whatever service the DBContext constructor needs to fetch the DbContextOptions. If I instead call a parameterless constructor for the DbContext, and hard-code the connection string in the DBContext's "OnConfiguring()" then this does work, but for obvious security reasons we cannot allow hard-coded connection strings in code.

**4. Injecting a "DbContextFactory" to create the new DbContext in the "using" block instead of passing in the options**

This has been suggested elsewhere, but just seems to result in the same error as above; "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: "IServiceProvider". Again, I have to assume that this is because the factory object is still taking in the DbContextOptions which are dependency-injected in, and whatever fetches this is being disposed of too early for some reason.

It feels like I am missing something fundamental here, but not having worked with .NET Core dependency injection in detail before, I'm not sure exactly what it is. Obviously what I would like to happen is that a new DBContext is created for each of the four ajax calls, but it seems that they are all sharing. How can I made it so that they use seperate DBContexts, bearing in mind the things that I've tried above?

Below is a sample of my code, I cannot copy and paste complete examples so this is not my *exact* code, but will hopefully provide some insight:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient(IUserService, UserService);
    services.AddTransient(IUserRepository, UserRepository);

    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext(options => options.UseSqlService(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));


}


public class UserRepository : BaseRepository, IUserRepository
{
    public MyDbContext Context;

    public UserRepository(MyDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public async Task<DbUser> GetUserByUsername(string userName)
    {
        return await Context.DbUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);
    }

}

public class UserService : IUserService
{

    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository /* Other repositories and services go here */)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }


    public async Task<SimpleUser> GetUser(string userName)
    {
        SimpleUser user = new SimpleUser();
        DbUser dbUser = await _userRepository.GetUserByUsername(userName);

        if(dbUser == null)
            //Code to either fetch user a different way or create a new one        

        user = new SimpleUser { UserName = dbUser.UserName, DisplayName = dbUser.FullName;};

        return user;
 
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you setting up Dependency Injection.  Minimally post your service configuration code, and your Service and Repository implementation.

Comment: Hi @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I've added some minimal code, note that this is not the complete code but hopefully this is enough to see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Likely a missing `await` somewhere on a task that includes a database call.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I'm 99% sure that everything that can possibly be awaited is being awaited, but would awaits be enough to make sure that this is thread safe? Surely the await only waits for the operation running on the current thread, it wouldn't affect what's being done by the other other three threads surely?

Comment: There should be at most one database call per DbContext, usually created by DI within a service scope, which kestrel will create per HttpRequest. Miss an await, and you might start a second query on the same context.

Comment: why aren't you just work with tasks whats the problem with tasks? why are you trying to generate new context for request?!